# I'm parsing the output of `ls` and something went wrong

Tags: bash, scripts

I made this simple script to copy a file recursively to many sub-directories. Here I am showing the problem for 3 sub-directories. I have 3 sub-directories and 2 files in a directory as follows

```
0.003/  0.007/  0.015/  program.cpp  driver.sh*
```

I want to copy `program.cpp` to all these sub-directories using `myscript.sh` shown below:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    mydir=`pwd`

    for i in `ls -la $mydir | grep "[0-9]$" | awk '{print $NF}'`
    do
        if [ -e $mydir/$1 ]
        then
            echo "cp -i $1 $i/"
        else
            echo "File \"$1\" not found in current directory"
        fi
    done
```

I have put the `cp` inside `echo` to test the code. The output is strange,

```
cp -i program.cpp 32/
cp -i program.cpp 0.003/
cp -i program.cpp 0.007/
cp -i program.cpp 0.015/
```

The output of `ls -la`

```
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x. 5 gulu workg 4.0K Nov 29  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 gulu workg 4.0K Nov 29  2013 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 gulu workg 4.0K Nov 26 19:09 0.003
drwxr-xr-x. 2 gulu workg 4.0K Nov 26 19:09 0.007
drwxr-xr-x. 2 gulu workg 4.0K Nov 26 19:09 0.015
-rw-r--r--. 1 gulu workg 4.2K Nov 29  2013 program.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 gulu workg  982 Nov 26 08:22 driver.sh
```

The output of `ls -la $mydir | grep "[0-9]$" | awk '{print $NF}'`

```
0.003
0.007
0.015
```

There are only three values in `i` then how is it producing four output? Anyway I have solved the problem with an additional condition `[ -d $mydir/$i ]`. But my question is how the script is producing the first line `cp -i driver.sh 32/`?

Comment: You could match the first "d" of the  list. Note that awk can do what grep does: `ls -la $mydir| awk '/^d.*[0-9]$/ {print $NF}'`

Comment: @Emmanuel yes it is a better proposal in fact. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This illustrates why you should NEVER rely on parsing the output of the `ls` command to iterate over directory contents - use a simple shell glob instead e.g. to match any filename ending in a digit

```
for f in $mydir/*[0-9]
do
    if [ -e $mydir/$1 ]
    .
    .
done
```

As to how it is producing the line `cp -i driver.sh 32/`, you can see that when you grep for digits in the output of `ls -la`, it is matching the `total: 32K` line as well as the wanted directory names.

Comment: Ohh! now I got it when you point out of `ls`. I was finding flaw here and there before. Actually in my `.bashrc` I put an alias for `ls` as `'ls -h --color=auto'`. That is why output of `ls -la` shown `total 32K` and filtered through `grep` with field ends with number discard it. But when the script is running I think it is using `/bin/ls` and taking four values reading first line as `total 32`. I learned a good lesson. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates why you should NEVER rely on parsing the output of the ls command to iterate over directory contents - use a simple `find` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d --regex './[0-9]+$' -exec cp $1 {} \;
```