# How can I download and extract an archive using a script (how can I reliably specify the file that was downloaded to a subsequent command)?

Tags: downloads, wget, archive

I want to write a script that downloads an archive from an URL (using `wget`) and extracts that archive (e.g. using `atool`, see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/atool)).

Unfortunately, I do not know where `wget` saves the downloaded file to. My script is parametrized by the URL, so **I do not know the URL while I am writing the script**.

**How can I extract a file downloaded by `wget`, if I do not know the location that `wget` saves to**? Note that I want to extract the downloaded file, so the file extension may be important.

---

In general, it is hard/impossible to predict the location that `wget` saves to. As a few examples,

- `wget example.com` creates the file `index.html`
- Running `wget example.com` a second time creates the file `index.html.2`
- `wget http://dis.images.s3.amazonaws.com/105024.jpeg` creates the file `105024.jpeg`
- `wget "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868"` creates the file `index.html?LinkID=760868`
- `wget --content-disposition "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868"` creates the file `code_1.19.1-1513676564_amd64.deb`

Comment: Not really sure what you want. As in your last example, you already _know_ the filename, as you provided it in the URL. And in the other examples, you just address an entry URL without the option `-r` - this will most likely return sort of `index.html`. Or is your problem the version number in the last example? Or the creation of a directory structure (you can avoid this by providing "Directory Options" (see `man wget`).

Comment: If you don't need to have the progress indicator and the like, your 4th attempt could work like `wget .... 2>&1 | grep 'Saving to' |  ....`, thus avoiding the big log file. If for any reason you want the output on screen, you may use `tee` for a second pipe: `... 2>&1 |  tee >(grep 'Saving to' > name.txt)`. And then read and process from that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's *very* unclear what you're actually after: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight **exactly** what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what you're asking. See the [tour] and the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. Also, please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.

Comment: @Peter Then change it, there's nothing wrong with that, even if you rewrite it from scratch! Just explain your real problem and what you want to achieve in the end – maybe there's a very simple solution after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make `wget` output to a temporary file. Have a look at `mktemp`, which lets you make a temporary file in a safe manner:

```
[~]$ filename=$(mktemp)
[~]$ echo $filename
/tmp/tmp.DglaA1x2Z0
[~]$ wget -O $filename www.example.com
--2017-12-29 22:15:28--  http://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 93.184.216.34, 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|93.184.216.34|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1270 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/tmp.DglaA1x2Z0’

100%[======================================>] 1,270       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2017-12-29 22:15:30 (156 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/tmp.DglaA1x2Z0’ saved [1270/1270]
```

`mktemp` guarantees that the file name is unique, and that permissions are handled so that we don't end up writing to a file that is owned by some other user. The file is created by `mktemp` with safe permissions:

```
[~]$ ls -la $filename
-rw------- 1 vidarlo users 1270 Aug 10  2013 /tmp/tmp.DglaA1x2Z0
```

This way you will have a file name that is guaranteed not to be in use for anything, and you are certain you won't be subject to race conditions because another user tricks you into writing into a file with disastrous results.

Now that you have a file, with a determined filename, you can run `file` to determine what kind of archive it is:

```
[/tmp]$ file -i foo.tar
foo.tar: application/x-tar; charset=binary
[/tmp]$ file -i foo.7z
foo.7z: application/x-7z-compressed; charset=binary
```

This does not rely on what the remote server tells us. The server could tell you the extension - or not. A php script can serve a perfectly valid tar archive, without ever telling you that it's a tar archive.

In addition we save the content to a safe place, avoiding race conditions.

Supporting a large number of archive formats can become unwieldy using this approach, but it's certainly better than using simply the filename extension from the webserver giving us the archive.

Note that you should *never* [parse ls](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383437/im-parsing-the-output-of-ls-and-something-went-wrong), as it may have very many unintended consequences.

Comment: This sounds like a X-Y problem. Why do you need the filename? Why do you need the metadata saved in the filename? Is it an alternative to parse the URL, or check the header for a filename?

Comment: As a refinement: create a temporary **directory** and have wget download there. You should then get only one file there, with the name as you need. See `mktemp -d`

Comment: Ah! But you don't! Use `file` command to get the archive type. That is *far* more reliable than relying on the filename. What if I hand you the URL example.com/download.php? This is exactly what I mean by X-Y problem...

Comment: Thanks, that works! I even noticed that `atool` can extract archives based on the information from `file`. So, for example `wget -O $filename "www.example.com/archive.zip"; atool -x $filename` works just fine.

Comment: To declutter, I have removed my comments referring to the previous version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `wget` saves to the `.` directory. However, you can override this by using the `-P` or `--directory-prefix` option. So, to save files into `/tmp/some_folder`, you'd use `wget ... -P tmp/some_folder ...`. The "trick" is understanding the right terminology used (prefix doesn't seem particularly intuitive).

Details for using `wget` can be found locally at the `man wget` command, or [online here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: Still, this does not tell me the name of the downloaded file. Or are you suggesting I use `ls` to determine the name, hoping that the "prefix folder "has been empty before my download?

Comment: @Peter, you may want to edit your question, as I read your request "I want to know where wget saved the file to" literally.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Is it clear(er) now?

Comment: @Peter, to answer the question in your comment: if the prefix folder doesn't exist, `wget` will create it. You can use this to your advantage. However, I'd be careful about parsing an `ls` output (use a shell glob instead or even a `find`).