# How to loop with variable as a line, instead of a word of a text?

Tags: command-line, bash

This is INPUT:

```
$ ls -1  # list folder name in current folder.
the cat
the dog
the rat

$ for var in $(ls -1); do echo $var; done # the command
```

This is OUTPUT that it did:

```
the
cat
the 
dog
the 
rat
```

This is OUTPUT that I need:

```
the cat
the dog
the rat
```

Comment: How about: `ls | while read line ; do echo $line ; done`

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/questions/383437/im-parsing-the-output-of-ls-and-something-went-wrong .  `for var in *; do echo $var; done`

Comment: @mook765 That's fine for looping over file names, but doesn't work for output from other programs, in case OP is just using `ls` as an example to illustrate.

Comment: @xiota That's correct, the problem is parsing the output of `ls`... Why I should assume that OP is using `ls` just as an example, I look at it as a specific problem as the question is written.

Comment: Duplicate on U&L: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file

Comment: [Bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using `ls` only as an example to illustrate output that may contain spaces, you can try this (replace `ls` with your command):

```
ls | while IFS= read -r line ; do
   echo "$line"
done
```

Without `IFS=`, the `read` command strips whitespace at the beginning and end of each line. Without `-r`, it treats `\` at the end of a line of input as a line continuation character, and just removes other `\` characters.

Note that `ls` itself defaults to one file per line when piped, even when you don't pass `-1`. (It's possible to have *more than one line per file*, though, because filenames are permitted to contain newline characters.) When piped, `ls` also disables color, if normally enabled.

To process a file, you can try:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
   echo "$line"
done < file.txt
```

If you want to loop over filenames, `bash` has the capability built-in, without parsing `ls`:

```
for file in * ; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Instead of writing `$(ls -1)`, just write `*`. This is a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

By itself, `*` expands to a list of files (regular files, directories, etc.) in the current directory. By default, files whose names start with `.` are omitted, which is also the behavior of `ls` and is what you usually want.

```
$ for f in *; do echo "$f"; done
the cat
the dog
the rat
```

Globbing is also called [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) or pathname expansion.

In general, it is best to [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Attempts to do so are [almost always incorrect and usually quite complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). When your goal is to extract and use the filenames as arguments to a command, as in the question asked here, it's not just difficult but in practice *impossible* to write a correct `ls`-parsing solution. The `ls` command produces output intended to be read by a human. Filenames can contain any character except `/` and the null character, even newlines. Furthermore, the most common ways people try to parse the output of `ls` break on extremely common filenames, like any filename that has a space in it. **In this case, the difference in complexity is stark: all you need is `*`.**

The other big thing to be careful about here is [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting). When you write [a shell loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) (which it itself [often best avoided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)), [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of the loop variable--`$f` in this example--should nearly always be enclosed in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes), as shown above. Otherwise, the shell tries to perform [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and (in this case, additional and unwanted) [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion). If you can't clearly explain why you're not in one of the rare scenarios where a variable expansion must be unquoted, [you should quote it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells).

Finally, note that many commands treat arguments specially, in some or all positions, when the arguments start with `-`. The main reason for this is that most commands accept options introduced by `-`, like `-l` (though some commands also take `-` by itself to mean [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) or [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))). But it's possible for filenames to start with `-`. Many, though not all, commands accept `--` to indicate the end of options, so that subsequent arguments will be interpreted as filenames even if they start with `-`. An even more broadly applicable solution is to ensure that files are specified with paths that *don't* start with `-`, for example, by [expanding the glob `./*` instead of `*`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#line-57). As for `echo`, it doesn't treat `--` specially, and the output you said you needed doesn't have the trailing `./`; to be robust in the face of filename that start with `-` (like `-n`, which tells `echo` to suppress the final newline), you can replace `echo` with `printf '%s\n'`.

*Although `*` has been mentioned elsewhere on this page, I think it deserves its own answer. Globbing (with `*`) is the only reasonable solution to the actual task this question presents. It is not an alternative to using `ls` with command substitution or piping the output of `ls` to `while`--because those techniques just don't do the right thing and should never be used. It is simply not feasible to make those other approaches work correctly with `ls`.*

Answer (score 0):

You should first set IFS (Internal Field Separator) to newline, then

`IFS=$'\n' && for var in $(ls -1); do echo $var; done`

will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapfile to read lines from the standard input into an indexed array:

`mapfile -t < <(ls -1); for i in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do echo $i; done`