# Bash: variable is not full read in `for` because line contains blank spaces

Tags: bash, scripts, cat

In `for` command, variable is not fully saved because of blank spaces.

Source file `in.csv`:

```
VPricingCurrency,Currency,Transactions,VPricingCurrency,Deal,VPricingCurrency
CustomerPriceGroup,Customer Price Group,AccountDS,AccountType,AccountDS,AccountType
```

Command:

```
for i in $(cat in.csv);
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Output:

```
VPricingCurrency,Currency,Transactions,VPricingCurrency,Deal,VPricingCurrency
CustomerPriceGroup,Customer
Price
Group,AccountDS,AccountType,AccountDS,AccountType
```

How to get second line full, with blank spaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make IFS delimit by endline.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat in.csv);
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

got two lines as per the input file

VPricingCurrency,Currency,Transactions,VPricingCurrency,Deal,VPricingCurrency
CustomerPriceGroup,Customer Price Group,AccountDS,AccountType,AccountDS,AccountType

Comment: some notes here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060636/when-do-i-set-ifs-to-a-newline-in-bash

Comment: I replicated your example, worked for me.

Comment: and I found this here   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167256/how-to-loop-with-variable-as-a-line-instead-of-a-word-of-a-text

Comment: and if using output to variable instead of from text (which my answer does not work with to parse (loop through) line by line, it is still one big string without line breaks.) 

count=0; mapfile  filearray < <( ls ); for i in "${filearray[@]}"; do count=$((count+1)); echo ""$count" "$i""; done

Answer (score 3):

To avoid word splitting by the shell, use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do 
  echo "$i"
done < in.csv
VPricingCurrency,Currency,Transactions,VPricingCurrency,Deal,VPricingCurrency
CustomerPriceGroup,Customer Price Group,AccountDS,AccountType,AccountDS,AccountType
```

See also:

- [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)
- [Bash Pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Yes, I used then immedietelly, but I just wanna to know why the line is readed in `for` wrong (if case of spaces). Thanks.